# Postal codes of China

Tags: shapefile, data, csv, china

Where can I find geodata with postal codes of China with an open license (commercial use is allowed)?

Comment: The [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be the place to ask this.

Answer (score -3):

You can find Chinese postal code data through this website. It is worth mentioning that these data are publicly available.

[Postal code list (Chinese)](https://www.youbianku.com/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E9%82%AE%E6%94%BF%E7%BC%96%E7%A0%81)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I've edited out a link which does not answer the question and which your profile indicates you might be affiliated with. Please note that this is considered [spam](/help/promotion) by our guidelines.